# How does " { $set: update }" work in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have seen the following code in a NodeJS tutorial video:

```
exports.updateDocument = (db, document, update, collection, callback) => {
    const coll = db.collection(collection);
    return coll.updateOne(document, { $set: update }, null);
};
```

But I can't understand how this part of code `{ $set: update }` works?

Comment: Better explained [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/)

Comment: Here `update` is the object which contains the `key and value` to be updated. for ex: {"email":"a@gmail.com"}. So email will be updated to `a@gmail.com`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[$set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) is a mongo update operator. Using the $set operator you can change the value for a field or even assign new fields to a document.

In the tutorial that you follow the `update` parameter will be a JSON object that contains the fields and values that will be set/updated in a document that matches the query filter `document`. Since you are using `updateOne` if multiple documents match the `document` filter then the only the first one will be updated.

Reference for the NodeJS MongoDB driver - https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.4/api/Collection.html#updateOne